# How can I pass multiple std::filesystem options?

Tags: c++, filesystems, std

Here is my recursive copy line:

```
fs::copy(line, backupLocation, fs::copy_options::recursive);
```

I want to have it be both recursive and update existing.
So something like:

```
fs::copy(line, backupLocation, fs::copy_options::recursive, fs::copyoptions::update_existing);
```

The above is invalid. How do I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_options:

> copy_options satisfies the requirements of BitmaskType

This means you should be able to OR them together:

```
fs::copy(line, backupLocation, fs::copy_options::recursive | fs::copyoptions::update_existing);
```